How to get list of column names from a query that won't return any rows
I am using MySQL, ExpressJS, and Sequelize to build a function that returns a list of columns from a given SQL query. The function should work even if the query returns no rows.
Here is the current implementation of my function:
async getColumnsFromQuery ( query ) {
    try {
        let queryResponse = await db.sequelize.query ( query, {
            type: db.sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
        });
        
        let columns = [];
        
        if ( queryResponse.length > 0 ) {
            columns = Object.keys( queryResponse[ 0 ] );
        }
        
        return columns;

    } catch ( err ) {
        throw err;
    }
}

This function works perfectly when the query returns rows, but if the query returns no rows, the columns array is empty. I need to ensure that the function still returns the correct column names even when no data is returned.
I tried using INFORMATION_SCHEMA , SHOW COLUMNS or DESCRIBE but they are only for tables not queries.

queryResponse[1] is the metadata of the query. I expect it's in there somewhere.

Try using console.log(queryResponse[1]) to see if the column names are in there.

@Barmar the queryResponse is an array that holds the rows generated by executing the query that was passed to the function.
I tried using console.log(queryResponse); and i got  { id: 53, name: "John Doe", Gender: "M", ... }
Thanks for the response!

The documentation says it's an array of [results, metadata]. results is an array of the rows returned by the query. metadata is additional information.

The output you show looks like queryResponse[0][0].

Actually, maybe using type: db.sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT makes it leave out the metadata and just return the results. Try it without that.

@Barmar I tried using type: db.sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT and without it, both ways I get 2 null arrays. (2) [Array(0), Array(0)]

I think I was able to find a way to get all the column names from a query including the datatypes of columns.
I used node-sql-parser a library that parses SQL statements.
By using the result I got from parsing the query, I was able to get all the column names.
Here is how I did it:
const { Parser } = require('node-sql-parser');

// For SELECT TableName.* FROM ....
getAllColumnsFromAllTables (allTableAllColumns) {
    const TablesFromDB = Object.keys(allTableAllColumns);
    return TablesFromDB.map(dbTable => {
        return allTableAllColumns[dbTable].columns;
    });
}
// For SELECT TableName.* FROM ....
getAllColumnsFromATable(allTableAllColumns, tableAlias) {
    const TablesFromDB = Object.keys(allTableAllColumns);
    for ( let i = 0 ; i < TablesFromDB.length; i++ ) {
        if (TablesFromDB[i].toLowerCase() === tableAlias[table].toLowerCase()) {
            // let tableColumns = allTableAllColumns[TablesFromDB[i]].columns.map( column => `${table.as ? table.as : table.table}.${column}`)
            return allTableAllColumns[TablesFromDB[i]].columns;
        }
    }
}
// For SELECT TableName.ColumnName FROM ....
getAColumnFromATable(allTableAllColumns, tableAlias, col) {
    const TablesFromDB = Object.keys(allTableAllColumns);
    for ( let i = 0 ; i < TablesFromDB.length; i++ ) {
        if (TablesFromDB[i].toLowerCase() === tableAlias[table].toLowerCase()) {
            for (let j = 0; j < allTableAllColumns[TablesFromDB[i]].columns.length; j++) {
                const dbCol = allTableAllColumns[TablesFromDB[i]].columns[j];
                if (dbCol.COLUMN_NAME.toLowerCase() === col.expr.column.toLowerCase()) {
                    return dbCol;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
// For SELECT ColumnName FROM ....
getAColumnFromAllTables (allTableAllColumns, col) {
    const TablesFromDB = Object.keys(allTableAllColumns);
    for ( let i = 0 ; i < TablesFromDB.length; i++ ) {
        for (let j = 0; j < allTableAllColumns[TablesFromDB[i]].columns.length; j++) {
            const dbCol = allTableAllColumns[TablesFromDB[i]].columns[j];
            if (dbCol.COLUMN_NAME.toLowerCase() === col.expr.column.toLowerCase()) {
                return dbCol;
            }
        }
    }
}
// Gets all columns of tables from database
async getAllColumnsOfTablesFromDB(tableNames) {
    const allTableAllColumns = {};

    var query = `
        SELECT 
            TABLE_NAME,
            COLUMN_NAME,
            DATA_TYPE,
            CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,
            NUMERIC_PRECISION,
            NUMERIC_SCALE
        FROM 
            INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE 
            TABLE_NAME IN (:tableNames)
            AND TABLE_SCHEMA = :DB_NAME;        
    `;

    await db.sequelize.query(query,  {
        replacements: {
            tableNames: tableNames,
            DB_NAME: this.dbConfig.database
        }
    }).spread((results, metadata) => {
        results.map(row => {
            if (allTableAllColumns[row.TABLE_NAME] && allTableAllColumns[row.TABLE_NAME].columns) {
                allTableAllColumns[row.TABLE_NAME].columns.push(row)
            } else {
                allTableAllColumns[row.TABLE_NAME] = {};
                allTableAllColumns[row.TABLE_NAME].columns = [row]
            }
        });
    });

    return allTableAllColumns;
}

async getColumnNames(ast) {
    let columns = [];
    let tableAlias = {};
    let tableNames = ast.from.map( t => t.table );
    let allTableAllColumns = await this.getAllColumnsOfTablesFromDB(tableNames);

    ast.from.forEach (table => {
        if (table.as) {
            tableAlias[table.as] = table.table
        } else {
            tableAlias[table.table] = table.table
        }
    });

    ast.columns.forEach(col => {
        if (col.expr.type === 'column_ref') {
            const table = col.expr.table;
            const column = col.expr.column === '*' ? '*' : `${table}.${col.expr.column}`;

            if (!col.expr.table && col.expr.column === '*') {
                // For SELECT * FROM ....
                return columns.push(...this.getAllColumnsFromAllTables(allTableAllColumns));
            } else if (col.expr.table && column === '*') {
                // For SELECT TableName.* FROM ....
                return columns.push(...this.getAllColumnsFromATable (allTableAllColumns, tableAlias));
            } else if (col.expr.table && col.expr.column) {
                // For SELECT TableName.ColumnName FROM ....
                return columns.push(this.getAColumnFromATable(allTableAllColumns, tableAlias, col));
            } else if (!col.expr.table && col.expr.column) {
                // For SELECT ColumnName FROM ....
                return columns.push(this.getAColumnFromAllTables(allTableAllColumns, col));
            }
        }
    });

    return columns;
}

async getColumnsFromQuery( query ) {
    try {
        await db.sequelize.query ( query ); // to check if query works
        const parser = new Parser();

        const pasredQuery = parser.astify(query);
        let columns = [];

        if (Array.isArray(pasredQuery)) {
            // only giving columns for 1st query if the result of parsed queries results in multiple queries
            columns = await this.getColumnNames( pasredQuery[0] );
        } else {
            columns = await this.getColumnNames( pasredQuery );
        }

        return response.SendResponse(res, columns, 0, "List of Columns");

    } catch ( err ) {
        return response.SendResponse(res, "An Error occoured", 1, err);
    }



}

Sample test of the above code:
let query = `
    SELECT * FROM Customer INNER JOIN database.Order ON database.Order.CustomerId = Customer.Id;
`
getColumnsFromQuery ( query );

Returns:
[{
            "TABLE_NAME": "Customer",
            "COLUMN_NAME": "Id",
            "DATA_TYPE": "int",
            "CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH": null,
            "NUMERIC_PRECISION": 10,
            "NUMERIC_SCALE": 0
        },
        {
            "TABLE_NAME": "Customer",
            "COLUMN_NAME": "Name",
            "DATA_TYPE": "varchar",
            "CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH": 10,
            "NUMERIC_PRECISION": null,
            "NUMERIC_SCALE": null
        },
        {
            "TABLE_NAME": "Customer",
            "COLUMN_NAME": "Age",
            "DATA_TYPE": "int",
            "CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH": 10,
            "NUMERIC_PRECISION": 10,
            "NUMERIC_SCALE": 0
        },
        .
        .
        .
        {
            "TABLE_NAME": "Order",
            "COLUMN_NAME": "OrderName",
            "DATA_TYPE": "varchar",
            "CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH": 10,
            "NUMERIC_PRECISION": null,
            "NUMERIC_SCALE": null
        },
        {
            "TABLE_NAME": "Order",
            "COLUMN_NAME": "OrderDate",
            "DATA_TYPE": "datetime",
            "CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH": null,
            "NUMERIC_PRECISION": null,
            "NUMERIC_SCALE": null
        },
        {
            "TABLE_NAME": "Customer",
            "COLUMN_NAME": "Age",
            "DATA_TYPE": "int",
            "CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH": 10,
            "NUMERIC_PRECISION": 10,
            "NUMERIC_SCALE": 0
        },
        .
        .
        .
]

You can modify the query in the getAllColumnsOfTablesFromDB to get any data about all the columns.
I tested it with many queries including queries that use alias for table names and also for columns.
This code can probably be refactored much further but this was the maximum I could do since I am not enough experienced to take this further.
